# c# linq. как получить 0 если значение не соответствуйтет выборке

Tags: c#, linq

Всем привет

Я плохо понимаю linq, поэтому возможно что то делаю не правильно.

Запрос:

```
var UserId = 88;
var query = projects
.Join(tasks,
  projects => projects.Id,
  task => task.ProjectId,
  (projects, task) => new { Projects = projects, Tasks = task })
.Where(c => c.Tasks.PerformerId == UserId)
.Select(c => c)
.GroupBy(x => x.Projects)
.ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key.Id, grp => grp.Count());
```

Есть 2 списка объектов, **projects** и **tasks**, они связанные c помощью **Id**, projects может содержать несколько tasks.

В tasks есть поле **PerformerId**.

Мне нужно получить колекцию projects с количеством tasks конкретного PerformerId (c.Tasks.PerformerId == UserId).

Если проще - список проектов, и сколько задач в проекте сделал конкретный PerformerId.

Код выше выполняет заданую задачу, пример:

query[0] - return 5
query[1] - return 3

В чем заключается проблема, query содержит в себе элементы  с value > 0.
Если в списке projects нет ниодного tasks.PerformerId ==  query вернет ошибку:
query[15] -  **System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException:** "The given key '15' was not present in the dictionary."

А мне нужно получить:
query[15] - return 0.

Как это можно сделать?
Спасибо

Comment: Вместо `query[key]` использовать `query.TryGetValue(key, out var value) ? value : 0;` Linq тут не при чем, это работа со словарем.

Comment: @aepot, у меня задача именно с помощью Linq сделать выборку и получить готовый словарь, если я что то делаю не правильно - не нужно решать задачу за меня, укажите просто в какую сторону мне идти что бы найти решение, спасибо:)

Comment: у вас правильная выборка, смысл хранить в словаре нули?

Comment: Ради всего святого, исправьте множественное число на единственное, везде, где нужно.

Comment: @aepot, это обучающий проект, мне нужно сформировать словарь использую всего один запрос. , Поэтому и не прошу решить его за меня, а подскать в какую сторону идти, linq  даеться очень тяжело, вроде и прочитал кучу информации, а связать все вместе не могу

Comment: Либо вы не знаете, как работает словарь, либо вы не поняли задание, поэтому хотите странного. Я не знаю, как помочь. Выглядит так что в словаре должны быть все существующие в базе ключи. Уберите Where для начала.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/uuZHS1nZ - оформите код в вопросе в таком виде. Чтобы его можно было скопировать и запустить. Списки tasks и projects заполните реальными данными. Тогда быстро получите ответ.

Comment: @aepot, мне нужно выбрать Tasks которые пренадлежат конктерному PerformerId, я делаю это с помощью Where. Задание получить количество tasks у projects по конкретному PerformerId где key - ProjectId, value - tasks Count.
Наверное вы правы, мне не зачем хранить нули.
Спасибо большое за помощь:)